# TableView (javaFX) is showing only blank lines

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, tableview

my `TableView` Is showing blank lines, what am I missing?

project link -> https://github.com/raphaelbgr/SwingSocketClient/tree/database

I am trying to gather information from the database and show it on this list view, the jdbc connection is perfect and working, however the tableView is not displaying the items, I've read 3 times the oracle tutorial but no luck.

```
public ObservableList<MessageDataTableModel> queryChatHistory(int rowLimit) throws SQLException {
    final ObservableList<MessageDataTableModel> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String query = "SELECT SERV_REC_TIMESTAMP, OWNERNAME, TEXT FROM MESSAGELOG LIMIT " + rowLimit;

    Statement st = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()) {
        while(rs.next()) {
            data.add(new MessageDataTableModel(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)));
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

And this calls the method above:

```
public void populateHistoryTable(int rowLimit) {
    DAO dao = new DAO();
    try {
        dao.connect();
        table_chathistory.setItems(dao.queryChatHistory(rowLimit));
        dao.disconnect();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the DataModel used, no Idea on what I am missing on it:

```
private SimpleStringProperty timestamp = new SimpleStringProperty();
private SimpleStringProperty screenname = new SimpleStringProperty();
private SimpleStringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty();

public MessageDataTableModel() {

}

public MessageDataTableModel(String timestamp, String screenname, String message) {
    this.timestamp = new SimpleStringProperty(timestamp);
    this.screenname = new SimpleStringProperty(screenname);
    this.message = new SimpleStringProperty(message);
}
public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp.set(timestamp);
}
public void setScreenname(String screenname) {
    this.screenname.set(screenname);
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message.set(message);
}
}
```

And a blank `TableView` appears, no idea on what I am missing

[image: And a blank list View appears, no idea on what I am missing]

Comment: A ListView is comprised of ListCells. `ListCell<T>` is the abstraction that is used to render the content in each of the rows (it is a subclass of `Cell<T>`). I look through the code you provided, but I do not see anything that looks like a ListCell factory.

Comment: I would also add that, since you wish to display rows that contain multiple fields (TimeStamp, Screen Name, Message) rather than just a single item in each row, you really should use a TableView in preference to a ListView.  The GUI component that you show us in your question appears to actually be a TableView.

Comment: This is a `ListView` or a `TableView`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, this is a `TableView` , I was so tired trying to fix this, that I totally forgot it was a `TableView`

Comment: So, what am I missing on this `TableView`?

Comment: Show the code where you define tablecolumn.setCellValueFactory() and if exists tablecolumn.setCellFactory() also.

Comment: As a side note, it is not good to create new SimpleStringProperty on every setter invocation. Instead init it in class block and then do  this.timestamp.set(timestamp); in setter method.

Comment: Can you post the link to the file where you define table_chathistory in your github repo.

Comment: just made the set modifications

Comment: I didn't use the tableCellFactory, the turorial I used didn't [Oracle Tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) , am I missing it?

Comment: It is not tableCellFactory, it is tablecolumn.setCellFactory(). You will need to use it when the cell is editable or contains more complex controls.

Comment: `@FXML private TableView table_chathistory;` is located [here](https://github.com/raphaelbgr/SwingSocketClient/blob/database/src/gui/fx/controllers/FXController.java)  on line 134, but I manipulate it [here](https://github.com/raphaelbgr/SwingSocketClient/blob/database/src/gui/fx/WindowDataFacade.java) on the class WindowDataFacade on line 330

Comment: The table is not editable, so it won't need a cellFactory, am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current tableView definition is as follows:

```
<TableView fx:id="table_chathistory" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="354.0" prefWidth="602.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Timestamp" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="85.0" text="Screen Name" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="441.0" text="Message" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

Here, the tableColumns are missing the [cellValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty). In FXML you can define it as

```
<TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Timestamp">
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="timestamp" />
    </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

and the data model class should have the accessors:

```
public class MessageDataTableModel
{

    private StringProperty timestampProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public void setTimestamp( String timestamp ) {
        this.timestampProperty.set( timestamp );
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return this.timestampProperty.get();
    }

    public StringProperty timestampProperty() {
        return this.timestampProperty;
    }
}
```

Note that for getter method that returns `ObservableValue` (timestampProperty() in the above) should have the propertyName + "Property", where the propertyName is "timestamp" in `<PropertyValueFactory property="timestamp" />`.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered, on the FXML file I had to input this to associate what data to incorporate on the TableView

`<TableView fx:id="table_chathistory" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="354.0" prefWidth="602.0">
<columns>
  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Timestamp"><cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="timestamp" /></cellValueFactory></TableColumn>`

`<TableColumn prefWidth="85.0" text="Screen Name"><cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="screenname" /></cellValueFactory></TableColumn>`

`<TableColumn prefWidth="441.0" text="Message"><cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="message" /></cellValueFactory></TableColumn>
</columns>`
`

And had to make a little modification on the dataModel, to retrieve the string values.

```
public class MessageDataTableModel {

private SimpleStringProperty timestamp = new SimpleStringProperty();
private SimpleStringProperty screenname = new SimpleStringProperty();
private SimpleStringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty();

public MessageDataTableModel() {

}

public MessageDataTableModel(String timestamp, String screenname, String message) {
    this.timestamp = new SimpleStringProperty(timestamp);
    this.screenname = new SimpleStringProperty(screenname);
    this.message = new SimpleStringProperty(message);
}
public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp.getValue();
}
public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp.set(timestamp);
}
public String getScreenname() {
    return screenname.getValue();
}
public void setScreenname(String screenname) {
    this.screenname.set(screenname);
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message.getValue();
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message.set(message);
}
}
```

And here we go, the results are here:
[image: worked!]