# TableView insert custom data rows dynamically in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

```
@FXML
    TableView<User_Info> table;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<User_Info, String> name;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<User_Info, String> username;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<User_Info, String> contact;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<User_Info, String> key;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<User_Info, String> mac;
    public ObservableList<User_Info> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(User_Info.fetch_List());

    // Event Listener on Button.onAction
    @FXML
    public void delete_user(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Autogenerated
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User_Info, String>("Name"));
        username.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User_Info, String>("Username"));
        contact.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User_Info, String>("Contact"));
        key.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User_Info, String>("Key"));
        mac.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User_Info, String>("Mac"));
        table.setItems(list);
    }
```

This is my controller where I am inserting the tableview and columns

```
 public class User_Info {
    static ArrayList<User_Info> list = new ArrayList<User_Info>();
    public String iName;
    public String iUsername;
    public String iContact;
    public long iKey;
    public long iMac;
    static LoginModel model = new LoginModel();

    public User_Info(String iName, String iUsername, String iContact, long iKey, long iMac) {
        this.iUsername = iName;
        this.iUsername = iUsername;
        this.iContact = iContact;
        this.iKey = iKey;
        this.iMac = iMac;

    }

    public static void prepareList() {
        list.clear();
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://consonant-vicinity.000webhostapp.com/retrievedata.php")
                    .timeout(10000).post();
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(document.text(), " ");
            while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String name = str.nextToken();
                String username = str.nextToken();
                String contact = str.nextToken();
                Long key = Long.parseLong(str.nextToken());
                Long mac = Long.parseLong(str.nextToken());

                if (!username.equals(model.getUsername())) {
                    list.add(new User_Info(name, username, contact, key, mac));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    public static ArrayList<User_Info> fetch_List() {
        return list;

    }

    public String get_Username() {
        return iUsername;
    }

    public String get_Contact() {
        return iContact;
    }

    public long get_Key() {
        return iKey;
    }

    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return iName;
}
    }
```

This is my custom class User_Info and here prepare_list is made to fetch data from some server and i am calling this method in my main method so just calling the list from Admincontroller where my tableview is present

output: no data is present in the table so i want all data should be their in that table

So please help!

Comment: Do you call it in the main method before or after launching the application. Also it seems like you're just asking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080442/the-table-cells-are-empty-in-my-tableview-javafx-scenebuilder) [old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497671/why-my-javafx-tableview-is-empty) [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146414/tableview-javafx-is-showing-only-blank-lines) again.

Comment: Why keep the items list within each rows data model? Seems quite unnecessary. Keep your UserInfo a simple POJO and populate your items list in the controller.